# Python: Make last item of array become the first

Tags: python, list

This is a very simple question, but I haven't seem to be able to find a satisfactory answer for it.

What is the best way, in Python, make the last item of a list become the first one "pushing" the rest of the list.

Something that does:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a[?????]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

I know I can always play with `len`, list concatenation...

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> [a[len(a)-1]] + a[0:len(a)-1]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

But that doesn't look right... "*Pythonic*", if you may

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Slicing is a little smarter than that; you can use *negative* indices to count from the end:

```
a[-1:] + a[:-1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a[-1:] + a[:-1]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

This works for an arbitrary number of elements to be moved to the front:

```
>>> a[-2:] + a[:-2]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Using slicing like this is comparable in speed to using `.insert()` + `.pop()` (on a short list):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a[-1:] + a[:-1]', 'a=[1,2,3,4]')
0.59950494766235352
>>> timeit.timeit('a.insert(0,a.pop(-1))', 'a=[1,2,3,4]')
0.52790379524230957
```

but wins hands down if you need to shift more than one element:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a[-2:] + a[:-2]', 'a=[1,2,3,4]')
0.58687901496887207
>>> timeit.timeit('a.insert(0,a.pop(-1));a.insert(0,a.pop(-1))', 'a=[1,2,3,4]')
1.0615170001983643
```

Comment: It still creates a new list (three lists actually) where it shouldn't create any.

Comment: @delnan: why shouldn't it create any?

Comment: Because it doesn't need to, and doing so adds several list traversals for absolutely no reason.

Comment: meh *doesnt need to* doesnt necessarily equate to *should not* imho... with smaller lists its obviously not going to effect performance ... with gigantic ones it might a little ...

Comment: @delnan This operation can't be done in less than O(n) when using regular lists.

Comment: @interjay Yes, I misunderstood the problem. Still, three list traversals (including allocations) is worse than one. And I'm not primarily concerned about performance (a C loop copying an array of `PyObject *`s is *fast*), it just seems like killing cockroaches with automatic weapons.

Answer (score 8):

```
In [103]: a=[1,2,3,4]

In [104]: a.insert(0,a.pop(-1)) # pop(-1) removes the last element 
                                # and use insert() to insert the popped
                                #  element at 0th endex

In [105]: a
Out[105]: [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look at [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque), which are optimized (memory wise) to do what you're asking, if you're doing a lot of these.

```
from collections import deque

>>> a = deque([1,2,3,4])
>>> a.rotate(1)
... deque([4, 1, 2, 3])
```

Since we're doing `timeit` to compare...

```
>>> setup = """from collections import deque
               a = deque([1,2,3,4])"""
>>> print timeit.timeit('a.rotate(1)', setup=setup)
... 0.219103839131
```

Comment: I've used deque a few times and I didn't think about this now, because I have a list stored as [1,2,3,4] that needs to be output (on a web page, actually) as [4, 1, 2, 3]. Memory is not an issue... I'm more interested in speed. I thought that converting a list to a deque and then rotate it is more time consuming than the slicing. What do you think? (I have no idea of deque performance)

Comment: @BorrajaX I added performance information.  Deque is *significantly* faster.

Comment: Arg... I'm afraid in this specific case it is not an option because rotate(1) doesn't return the deque, and all this process is done in a  template to generate html (so it needs one-liners only) Thank you very much for the hint, though

Comment: If you're only going to perform the rotation once, instantiating the deque has a bit of overhead that makes it slower than slicing the list.  I was going to suggest making a function that returns a deque and using that in your one-liner, but performance-wise, it looks like you'll be better served by list slicing, anyway.

Comment: @BorrajaX if you just need to _display_ the rotated list, why not just use a function to spit out items given an arbitrary ordering?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to dump an arbitrarily accessed list, as you mentioned in the comment to @kreativitea, re-ordering may not even be necessary, and you can design an arbitrary access generator instead:

```
size = 10
l = range(size)


# use a generator expression to yield slices of the list according 
# to your own order.
# note that no error checking is enforced, and that overlapping 
# and invalid accessRanges will work, so depending on the usage
# you have for this function, you might want to add some 
# sanity checks, like ensuring no overlap between accessRanges
# and that each item is accessed only once.
def ArbitraryListAccessor(listObj, accessRanges):
    for ar in accessRanges:
        for item in listObj[ar[0]:ar[1]]:
            yield item

# to dump the access-ordered list generator as a real list, you need to
# iterate over it, for example, with a list comprehension:
[i for i in ArbitraryListAccessor(l, ((-1,None), (0,-1)))]
# [9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It's slower than deque, but faster than creating new lists. For multiple iterations, it's about twice as slow as deque, but for a single run (e.g. just read the list once in an arbitrary order), it's comparable (e.g. order of microseconds.)

The benefit here is that you get to define any random access ranges you want to use. You could also replace the ranges in the function with `Slice` objects and implement it as regular list slices (but then you have provide the slice tuple or a slice object.)